# Mac OS System 1.0 Programming Language

Tags: macos, programming-languages, history

I started my early days programming in a Macintosh 128k (I was 10) and I don't quite remember the programming languages used. Any one does?

I would like to know the different programming languages available at that time for that platform.

Thanks

Comment: I want to know the different programming languages that could be used for System 1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Development was originally carried on the Lisa, using Pascal and assembler. Some time later native development environments started to appear for the Mac, e.g. TMS Pascal, MacPascal, Microsoft BASIC, MDS, and later, MPW, Think C, Think Pascal, CodeWarrior, etc.

Pascal was the original language for Mac OS programming, and all the documentation and APIs used Pascal, but there was a gradual migration towards C through the 1980s.

Comment: Yes it was Pascal. Reading about the Macintosh I found the source code for MacPaint & QuickDraw here: http://www.computerhistory.org/highlights/macpaint/ Boy, it does bring back memories. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes - I did quite a bit of Mac programming back in the 80s and 90s - mostly in Pascal - the MacPaint source code brings a lot if it back.

Answer (score 1):

I expect Macintosh Programmers Workbench (MPW) which was a "worksheet" environment, mainly driven on the command line, used Makefiles - not dissimilar to Unix development, using Pascal as the main language.

I don't remember if Hypercard was available that early but that's another possibility.